# Are 新規入国 and 再入国 mutually exclusive?

Tags: nuances

This is maybe not strictly a language question, apologies.

Is each time a person enters Japan considered a 新規入国 regardless if the person has the status of being able to 再入国 (permanent residents, etc.)?  Or is someone with this status considered to be 再入国ing and not 新規入国ing when the person goes abroad and returns?

Is each 入国 considered a 新規 even if it is a 再入国 , or are the two exclusive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer, this is not legal advice.

Based on personal experience and an explanation of these terms on page 2 [here](https://www.moj.go.jp/isa/content/930002505.pdf), these terms are mutually exclusive. See the linked source for full details, but to summarize:

> ...再入国の許可を受けていったん出国した後に再び入国した外国人を「再入国者」といい，それ以外の入国者を「新規入国者」という。

> Foreigners re-entering the country after having departed *with re-entry permission* are 再入国者, and foreigners to whom this does not apply are 新規入国者

In effect, this means that the only way that 再入国 applies is if you left Japan with valid re-entry permission, and are returning with that permission. This *generally* means you either left within the last year on a multiple-entry visa (which usually gives you re-entry within one year for free), or applied for a longer re-entry permit and then left.

新規入国 means that you are entering the country without any kind of re-entry permission, either because you have been issued a new visa which you received while outside the country, or because you are entering on a tourist visa/visa waiver (though this hasn't been possible since Japan closed down the first time).

Finally, note that these are technical immigration terms and not everyday words - I have had more than one native Japanese speaker ask for clarification of what exactly these terms mean.